# Klarna payment option not showing Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, klarna

I have enabled **Klarna** in the magento `store->paymentoptions` section. But it does not show on the frontend when going to the checkout and trying to select the payment option. If I enable other payment options then those are shown but not Klarna. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Check Your Credentials and run indexer:reindex command

Comment: @MuhammadAhmed that did not work sadly. Any more ideas?

Comment: any luck guys ?

Comment: I am having the same issue with both 2.3.1 and 2.3.2 - Klarna does not show as a checkout option on either. It does work on 2.2 but not on 2.3. If anyone knows of a solution, please let us know.

Comment: our karna_api.log file (enabled by setting "Debug" to yes in the config) shows 403 Forbidden errors when the checkout page tries to connect to Klarna (also "MERCHANT_INACTIVE"). We have tested this with different APIs but none of them worked.

Comment: ... the issue was an apparent backend setting at Klarna themselves. They just had it fixed this morning and it should now work on Magento 2.3.x

Answer (score 1):

Klarna will not show if you enter wrong credentials, Note it will not work for old klarna Merchant ID and secret code ,

Comment: I have created new account and trying with Magento v2.4.1 but still same 403 error

Answer (score 1):

I am getting below error in the Magento log file after adding Playground credential.

> [2021-03-18 12:55:09] klarnaDebugLogger.ERROR: Bad Response: Client error: `POST https://api-na.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/sessions` r>
> {
> "error_code" : "INVALID_OPERATION",
> "error_messages" : [ "" ],
> "correlation_id" : "efdf0a6c-ebca-4c8f-a7a3-dba93 (truncated...)